# Save a copy of a workbook using a cell reference, including macros and forms

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post here, and I am quite new to VBA, I could do with some help / advise please.

I have a book that contains multiple sheets with user login / permissions. I need to save a copy of the ( current ) open workbook in .xlsm-format ( including the macros ), with a name ref from cell "Z6" and remove one sheet from the copy ( this sheet has information that is not needed on any of the saved copies ).

I am working with the code below:

```
Sub SaveFileCopy()
   Dim x As Integer
   Dim FileName As String, FilePath As String
   Dim NewWorkBook As Workbook, OldWorkBook As Workbook
   Set OldWorkBook = ThisWorkbook
   With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False
   End With
   On Error Resume Next
   With OldWorkBook.Sheets("Reception Sheet")
      FilePath = "C:\HDMS\JOBS\" & .Range("Z6").value
      FileName = .Range("Z6").value & ".xlsm"
   End With
   MkDir FilePath
   On Error GoTo -1
   On Error GoTo myerror
   FilePath = FilePath & "\"
   For x = 2 To OldWorkBook.Worksheets.Count
      With OldWorkBook.Worksheets(x)
         If Not NewWorkBook Is Nothing Then
            .Copy after:=NewWorkBook.Worksheets(NewWorkBook.Worksheets.Count)
         Else
            .Copy
            Set NewWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
         End If
      End With
   Next x
   NewWorkBook.SaveAs FilePath & FileName, 52
myerror:
   If Not NewWorkBook Is Nothing Then NewWorkBook.Close False
   With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True
   End With
   If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox (Error(Err)), 48, "Error"
End Sub
```

I can get the file to save a new workbook, however it will not save any "Macros or Forms"

Comment: This will save it as `C:\HDMS\JOBS\Z6\Z6.xlsm`, not as `C:\HDMS\JOBS\Z6.xlsm`. Was that your intent? Are you looking at the right file?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply / advice  - When I save it now as as the code is. 1) A folder is created with a reference name taken from Cell "Z6" then within the created folder is the save book also have the Cell " Z6" reference name, the saved book  File Type = Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet (.xlsm) . but when the book is opened there are 0 Macros and 0 Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want to delete the first sheet, it's going to be easier to delete it after copying the entire workbook. This would also keep the forms and macros in the new one.

Something like this:

```
Sub SaveFileCopy()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim FileName As String, FilePath As String
    Dim NewWorkBook As Workbook, OldWorkBook As Workbook

    Set OldWorkBook = ThisWorkbook

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    With OldWorkBook.Sheets("Reception Sheet")
        FilePath = "C:\HDMS\JOBS\" & .Range("Z6").value
        FileName = .Range("Z6").value & ".xlsm"
    End With

    MkDir FilePath
    On Error GoTo -1

    On Error GoTo myerror
    FilePath = FilePath & "\"
    
    Set NewWorkBook = OldWorkBook 'you could do this with OldWorkBook as well but then the name might get confusing?
    
    NewWorkBook.SaveAs FilePath & FileName, 52
    NewWorkBook.Worksheets(1).Delete
    NewWorkbook.Save
myerror:
    If Not NewWorkBook Is Nothing Then NewWorkBook.Close False
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox (Error(Err)), 48, "Error"
End Sub
```

Hope this works :)

**EDIT (to keep OldWorkBook open):**

Instead of

```
Set NewWorkBook = OldWorkBook 'you could do this with OldWorkBook as well but then the name might get confusing?

    NewWorkBook.SaveAs FilePath & FileName, 52
```

Use this:

```
OldWorkBook.SaveCopyAs FilePath & FileName
    Set NewWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & FileName)
```

That should open the file and then the rest of the code continues with deleting the first sheet and closing it again.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I have tried to use the code supplied above, but now when I click "Save Btn ", I end up with a blank book. And when I check the destination folder there are no new stored Folders / Files. I can open the Original workbook and it is still intact. Any ideas as to why it is not saving the book at all now?

Comment: Have you put the code in ThisWorkBook? Can you go through the code step by step (with F8) and check if you see any irregularities?

Comment: Hi.
Question : Have you put the code in ThisWorkBook?
Yes : It is in the “master” book.
Question : Can you go through the code step by step (with F8) and check if you see any irregularities? 
Answer : As soon as I get to this line ( If Not NewWorkBook Is Nothing Then NewWorkBook.Close False ) the work book closes.  ( if I go to File > Open > choose the work book, I get error ( Path/File access error ) ( Run-time error ‘75’ )
 ). I have also noticed that whilst doing the ( "F8" ) check, the check skips the following two lines ( NewWorkBook.Worksheets(11).Delete //////  NewWorkBook.Save ).

Comment: Does the path/file already exist from your earlier tests? It's weird that it'd close just fine but not do the delete of the 1st (not 11th) worksheet and neither the save.

Comment: Yes the file path is correct. I have also created a "new book" and tried, this is also failing

Comment: I just tried again: Created a new workbook. Added two worksheets, the last one I called "Reception Sheet" and put the name "Test214" in Range("Z6"). Added my code above and adjusted to `OldWorkBook.Path & "\"` instead of the `"C:\HDMS\JOBS\"` for testing purposes. Saved my workbook and then ran my code, it does  everything it needs to: makes the folder, creates the copy (with code ofc) and deletes the first sheet.
Since you've already created the folder/file before, there shouldn't be any issues with the name in Z6 for you so I have no clue why this isn't working then, sorry :/

Comment: Thankyou for the update - I have done exactly as you have done and found it to work as well :). I do have 2 added questions please. 1) what is the best way to save the "New Book" in "JOBS" folder. 2) When I click "Save btn " to save the new file, the "Master" book closes, but Excel app stays open. Can the original book stay open to add more "jobs"?

Comment: 1) We're saving into their own folder since that's what you specified in your question/code. If you don't want to create their own folder, simply remove the ` & Range("Z6").Value` in the FilePath and the `MkDir FilePath`. Or if you meant that the OldWorkBook isn't in the "JOBS" folder, use the code in my answer instead of my test `OldWorkBook.Path` from previous comment.
2) Since we're using SaveAs, the MasterBook is used directly as the new workbook. I'll try to see if making a copy is easier or re-opening the original workbook is. Will update when I can.

Comment: See my Edit for updated code, it saves it as a copy (keeping the OldWorkBook open) and then opens the copy and does its thing.